# How to stop an elasticache node from with awscli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I'm new to aws and elasticache. I created a cluster for test, but now I want to stop the node.

So.. can I stop an elasticache node from with awscli? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd guess you want 'delete-cache-cluster:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticache/index.html

```
aws elasticache delete-cache-cluster --cache-cluster-id <value>
```

Comment: This deletes the cluster. is it possible to stop it temporarily?

Comment: @zaitsman It appears not. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46535278/is-it-possible-to-stop-nodes-in-aws-elasticache-cluster).

Answer (score 0):

Following command will give you all the nodes:

```
aws elasticache describe-cache-clusters --cache-cluster-id $cacheClusterId  --show-cache-node-info  --query 'CacheClusters[*].CacheNodes[*].[Endpoint.Address]'  --output text --region us-east-1
```